# How to hide in GAL zimbra account

Tags: zimbra

i am using zimbra. I am creating a lot of accounts and i wanted to know how to hide them in the GAL (global access list) with zmprov by bash.

Any will be appreciated.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the "zimbraHideInGal" attribute from that account.

You can do that for a single account with:

```
{name@domain|id|adminName} [attribute1 value1 etc]
```

This results in:

```
zmprov ma joe@domain.com zimbraHideInGal TRUE
```

"ma" means modify Account. You still have to replace the email address with the correct email address.

If you have more than one account, you can wrap a bash script aroud that to call zmprov for every account you have to set.

Check this [zmprov - Zimbra Wiki](https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zmprov) for more information.